# Prevent Google App Being Compiled with Admob

Tags: android, google-maps, admob

When using Google maps in an Android application, is it possible to stop admob being compiled with it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe dex will automatically strip out unused code, so your APK won't contain any references to Admob. If not you can always use Proguard to to do the same.

Comment: It does contain references to admob, how can I use proguard to strip it out?

Comment: Why is it a problem? And what references to Admob does it contain?

Comment: It just has the admob sdk packaged with it

Comment: And that's a problem because?